# ASP.net MVC 4 and BootStrap _NavBar Style issue

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

After changing my theme rrom default ASP.net MVC theme to BootStrap I got some styling issue in NavBar, **Log off** should be in same line with **Hello, admin**: 
[image]

This's my _NavBar.cshtml :

```
    @helper ActiveItem(string actionName, string controllerName, string areaName)
{
    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == actionName &&
            ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == controllerName &&
            (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] == null || ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == areaName))
    {
        @:active
    }
}

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navbar header and form mobile version -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PFE</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Menu Link list and Deconnexion button -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </p>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="@ActiveItem("Index", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="@ActiveItem("About", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li class="@ActiveItem("Contact", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this _LoginPartial.cshtml :

```
 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
  <text>
  Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
         @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
  </text>
}
else {
  <text>
  @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
  | @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
  </text>
}
```

Html code After interpted by Chrome:

```
 Hello, <a class="username" href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">admin</a>!
    <form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="FouTIIlrUNMPSCuPnaUtLA-zm5Q5ya2-24OFPZF5EWKECyyN7l4F1SOIClnfUU_2CzEbq6tQSAJ_EDKbLJLA6Hzc4Gc_OSTWbHfXmSdwV8E1" />     
     <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    </form>
```

How to fix it please?

Comment: If you have this problem only when user is logged in then it's probably because you wrapped LogOff in form and it's treated as block. And btw who does Logout functionality as form anyway? :P

Comment: Yeah logoff is in separated form and it's implemanted with `WebSecurity.Logout();`

Comment: Well can you check in ChromeDevTools that this form is in fact treated as block then?

Comment: I have Updated my post check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve I added the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` inside  a **DIV** tag like this :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is probably being treated as a block. Just use `display: inline-block` property on it and it should be fixed.

```
#logoutForm {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XdQA8/

Comment: Where to put it ? in wich file ?

Comment: @Chlebta You can do it in-line like so. `@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", style="display: inline-block;" }))`

Comment: in HTML code I got this `<form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post" style="display: inline-block;">` but it dosn't work same issue.